# What does the additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^3$ generated by the vertices of a regular polyhedron look like?

Tags: group-theory, polyhedra

Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the vertices of one of the regular polyhedra centered at the origin and let $G = \sum_{k=1}^n v_k \mathbb{Z}$, the additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^3$ generated by these vertices.

In some cases, like for a tetrahedron, cube, or octahedron, $G$ is a lattice. Is it always the case or are there some regular polyhedra that will yield a group [dense-in-itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense-in-itself)?

Clearly if one of these two results is true for a polyhedron, then it also applies to its dual. I don't have any intuition of the answer for the regular dodecahedron or icosahedron though, and even less for the non-convex regular polyhedra.

Comment: A fun question! :)

Comment: You do not need to distinguish convex and non-convex polyhedra, because each non-convex regular polyhedron has the same vertex set as one of the convex ones.

Comment: @M.Winter That's right I didn't realize this as I was writing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's first consider the corresponding question in the plane.  Consider the subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^2$ generated by the vertices of a regular $n$-gon centered at the origin.  Scaling and rotating, we may assume these vertices are the $n$th roots of unity when we identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$, so the subgroup in question is just the subring $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]\subset\mathbb{C}$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity.  By the theory of cyclotomic polynomials, the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has degree $\varphi(n)$ (where $\varphi$ is the totient function), so $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ has rank $\varphi(n)$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.  In particular, as long as $n\neq 1,2,3,4,6$, $\varphi(n)>2$ and so $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ must be dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

It follows that if you take the vertices of a regular $n$-gon in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for $n\neq 1,2,3,4,6$, the subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^3$ they generate will be dense in some plane parallel to the plane of the $n$-gon (namely, the plane you get by scaling away from the origin a factor of $n$, so that the subgroup will contain the center of the scaled $n$-gon as well as all its vertices and thus will contain the subgroup generated by those scaled vertices when you treat the center as the origin).  If you are taking the vertices of a polyhedron that has two non-parallel regular $n$-gons for $n\neq 1,2,3,4,6$ as faces, it then follows that the subgroup its vertices generate will be dense in all of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: I thought that studying the subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^2$ generated by the vertices of a face would help, but I'm not familiar enough with cyclotomic polynomials and subrings of $\mathbb{C}$ to have found the answer myself. Thank you!

Comment: While this is a good answer (+1) the explanation of the non-lattice nature of most $n$-gons is quite advanced. More low-level (visual) explanations are a available, e.g. [in this very nice video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=sDfzCIWpS7Q) by Mathologer.(Burkhard Polster).

Comment: @M.Winter Great video thank you for sharing!